# Rounding doubles to n decimal points using "round-to-even" in C++

Tags: c++, r, statistics, rounding, decimal-point

I want to implement a function in C++:

```
double round_to_even(double num, int decimal_places); 

/* rounds the first argument to three decimal places 
using round-to-even (unbiased rounding) */
```

which behaves the way rounding in R works, using a method known as round-to-even, unbiased rounding, or statistician's rounding: 
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Round.html
The best way to illustrate this is by a few examples from R, where decimal_place=3:

```
> round(0.1247,3) # rounding the first argument to three decimal places
[1] 0.125

> round(0.1244,3)
[1] 0.124
```

Notice how it behaves as you would expect, by rounding up when the digit to the right of the specified decimal_place is greater than 5 (here equal to 7), and truncating when it's smaller than 5 (here equal to 4). However, when the digit to the right of the specified decimal_place is equal to 5 (or at "midpoint") it behaves as follows:

```
> round(0.1255,3) # will round up
[1] 0.126

> round(.1275,3) # will round up
[1] 0.128

> round(0.1265,3) # will truncate
[1] 0.126

> round(0.1245,3) # will truncate
[1] 0.124
```

by rounding up when the digit to the left of decimal_place is odd and truncating when even.

Is there a concise way to implement this, and in particular without converting the digits to characters?

Edit: 
This is the best I could come up with:

```
double round_to_even(double number, int decimal_points) 
/* rounds the first argument to three decimal places
using round-to-even (unbiased rounding) */
{   
    double num_left = number, num_right = number;
    int digit_left, digit_right;

    num_left *= pow(10, decimal_points + 1);
    digit_left = fmod(num_left, 10);

    if (digit_left == 5) 
    {   
        num_right *= pow(10, decimal_points);
        digit_right = fmod(num_right, 10);

        if (digit_right % 2 == 0) // if even 
            return floor(number * pow(10, decimal_points)) / pow(10, decimal_points);
        else // otherwise it's odd
            return ceil(number * pow(10, decimal_points)) / pow(10, decimal_points);
    }
    else { // standard round-to-nearest
        return round(number * pow(10, decimal_points)) / pow(10, decimal_points);
    }
}
```

And I've tested it:

```
std::vector<double> test_vector({ 0.1247, 0.1244, 0.1255, 0.1275, 0.1265, 0.1245 });
std::vector<double> expected_values({ 0.125, 0.124, 0.126, 0.128, 0.126, 0.124 });

for (std::vector<double>::size_type i = 0; i < test_vector.size(); i++)
    std::cout << "expected: " << expected_values[i] << "\t got: " << round_to_even(test_vector[i], 3) << std::endl;
```

Which gives the following output:

```
expected: 0.125  got: 0.125 
expected: 0.124  got: 0.124
expected: 0.126  got: 0.126
expected: 0.128  got: 0.128
expected: 0.126  got: 0.126
expected: 0.124  got: 0.124
```

Comment: I just posted an attempt below. Should I have posted it as an edit?

Comment: Thanks, I've made the edit. But if this question belongs in the code review site, then I am happy to delete it.

Comment: Assuming the code works as intended and you want to know how to do achieve the same result, better (for some values of better), feel free to post it on CodeReview

Comment: A key design situation you've glossed over is whether numbers than are infinitesimally (by which I mean by the smallest possible amount given the floating point format in use) smaller than the ...5 value that would round up - *perhaps* only due to having to round them to a representable value but you never can be sure - should be treated as 5 and rounded up, or not.  Unless you do that quite a lot of values that you'd expect to get rounded up will actually round down.  Still, sometimes rounding errors accumulate and you need two "infinitesimal" tolerance, or three - there is no perfect answer.

Comment: Note that R is actually rounding the *wrong* way for `0.1265`: it should be rounded up to `0.127`.  (Because with binary floating-point arithmetic what you see is not what you get, and the value that was specified as `0.1265` is actually stored as `0.126500000000000001332267629550187848508358001708984375`.  So it's above the halfway case.)

Comment: @Mark That's a good point. I thought it only examined the digit in question as an integer (5 instead of 5.00000000000001332267629550187848508358001708984375) but that doesn't seem to be the case, as it gives results which are inconsistent with what I thought rounding to even should do. 
For example: round(.126500,3) = 0.126, while round(.126509,3) = 0.127

Comment: *"by rounding up when the digit to the left of decimal_place is odd and truncating when even."* is not what's happening at all... it's actually comparing to `5`, not concerned with odd and even.  In terms of C++ `double` representation, you'll likely find it effectively random whether a "0.X...5" value's closest-possible representation is ...5000... or ...4999...  For example, `.1165'`s `double` representation is higher than .1165, but `.1175'`s is lower.

Comment: @Tony Is it the case that it truncates when less than 5 and rounds up if greater or equal to 5, and that the behavior I am seeing is due to how the numbers are internally represented?

Comment: @Aciel: that's what happens with `ceil`, `floor` and `round` - yes; but remember that the `double` value you're passing to them may not be the original `number` argument passed to `round_to_even()` - all the `pow` calls, multiplications etc. can result in rounding errors, and on some systems they can even vary with optimisation level (e.g. on common Intel x86-family CPUs optimisation can affect when the CPU stops using an 80 bit FPU registers and rounds back to a 64 bit value that can be stored in an actual `double` in memory: when that happens can change what reaches `floor`, `ceil` etc..

Comment: @Tony, the documentation seems to agree with my question https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Round.html "Note that for rounding off a 5, the IEC 60559 standard is expected to be used, ‘go to the even digit’."

Comment: @Tony I realise that variables are not always fully displayed and that the value can differ internally. However, in the examples I gave above (in R), I am typing numbers into the round() function directly rather than passing variables. The documentation does explicitly state the round() uses the round-to-even method at midpoint.

Comment: @Aciel: oh ok - sorry - had skimmed over that yesterday and forgotten it was part of your desired R behaviour.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
double round(double d, int n) {
    double last = d * pow(10, n + 1);
    int last_dig = floor(last) % 10;
    if (last_dig != 5)
        return reg_round(d, n); //round as normal

    double pre_last = d * pow(10, n);
    int pre_last_dig = floor(pre_last) % 10;
    if (pre_last_dig %2 == 0)
        return floor(d,n); //last digit is even, floor.
    else
        return ceil(d,n); //last digit is odd, ceil.
}
```

Assuming `reg_round` is normal round.

Comment: "last_dig" and "pre_last_dig" have been used without being initialized. I assume you meant to type "last"? when I make this substitution it doesn't give the correct answers to the test above.

Comment: @Aciel yeah typo. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks. This passes the test cases above, but I had to implement ceil, floor and round, as the c++ versions take a single argument and round to int (unless there is a library I should have included?)

Comment: I don't think that's the correct solution - it doesn't check whether there are no more digits after the 5. For instance 1.00051 should round to 1.001 for n = 3, but it does to 1

Answer (score 1):

I had to look into this recently for work, I looked at dtoa.c but the cut-down version I tried to use seemed to have issues on windows, probably my fault, but in the end I my own implementation of round-to-even aka banker rounding/statisticians rounding:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void bankerRound(double d, int decimals, char *buffer, int bufferLength) {
    const auto powerTen = pow(10.0, decimals);
    double intPart = 0;
    double fractionPart = fabs(modf(d, &intPart));
    double fractionRaised = fractionPart * powerTen;
    double fractionRaisedAndRounded;
    double fractionRaisedIntComponent = NAN;
    if (modf(fractionRaised, &fractionRaisedIntComponent) == 0.5) {
        if ((long) fractionRaisedIntComponent % 2 == 0) {
            fractionRaisedAndRounded = floor(fractionRaised);
        } else {
            fractionRaisedAndRounded = ceil(fractionRaised);
        }
    } else {
        fractionRaisedAndRounded = round(fractionRaised);
    }

    if (fractionRaisedAndRounded >= powerTen) {
        fractionRaisedAndRounded -= powerTen;
        intPart = intPart < 0 ? intPart - 1 : intPart + 1;
    }

    snprintf(buffer, static_cast<size_t>(bufferLength), "%.0lf.%0*.0lf", intPart, decimals, fractionRaisedAndRounded);
}
```

modf separates the integer component and fractional component of a double - meaning we don't need to raise the double to a large power, potentially overflowing.  However multiplying a fraction can result in inaccuracies creeping in because values cannot be exactly represented in base-2, so I would only use this function if you're only using it to something like 6 decimal places.  Otherwise it might be better to try and get dtoa.c or the newer Ryū algorithm to work.